# algorithm to find the number of boxes needed for different lengths of cable

Tags: algorithm

Given that someone can purchase cable in boxes of 10K, 5K, 2K, 1K feet.

Suppose they have 100 cable drops of different lengths.

I want to determine the best combination boxes they would need to purchase to 
minimize the amount of wasted cable to create their drops.

What is the best way to go about doing this? I'm not good with algorithms :(

Simplified example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

You have the following cable lengths:

1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2

You have the following box sizes:

5, 10, 20

Given the cable lengths, to minimize waste you would need to purchase:

2 x 20 boxes

1 x 5 box

---

20 = 7, 3, 6, 4

20 = 5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 1

5 = 1, 2

=======================================

Just for anyone else that needs something like this in the future. Here is the completed code to the original problem. It's a Frankenstein from cutting and pasting and gluing together different solution that I found, though it works on my box . I want to thank @bryan60 again for the initial part of this solution, you did an outstanding job and really help get this solution off the ground.

```
    "use strict";

    //Knapsack algorithm
    //==================
    // wikipedia: [Knapsack (0/1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_Knapsack_Problem)
    // Given a set `[{weight:Number, benefit:Number}]` and a capacity,
    // find the maximum value possible while keeping the weight below
    // or equal to the capacity
    // **params**:  
    //    `capacity`  : Number,  
    //    `items`     : [{w:Number, b:Number}]  
    // **returns**:  
    //    An object containing `maxValue` and `set`
    function knapsack(items, capacity) {
        var idxItem = 0,
            idxWeight = 0,
            oldMax = 0,
            newMax = 0,
            numItems = items.length,
            weightMatrix = new Array(numItems + 1),
            keepMatrix = new Array(numItems + 1),
            solutionSet = [];

        // Setup matrices
        for (idxItem = 0; idxItem < numItems + 1; idxItem++) {
            weightMatrix[idxItem] = new Array(capacity + 1);
            keepMatrix[idxItem] = new Array(capacity + 1);
        }

        // Build weightMatrix from [0][0] -> [numItems-1][capacity-1]
        for (idxItem = 0; idxItem <= numItems; idxItem++) {
            for (idxWeight = 0; idxWeight <= capacity; idxWeight++) {

                // Fill top row and left column with zeros
                if (idxItem === 0 || idxWeight === 0) {
                    weightMatrix[idxItem][idxWeight] = 0;
                }

                // If item will fit, decide if there's greater value in keeping it,
                // or leaving it
                else if (items[idxItem - 1].w <= idxWeight) {
                    newMax = items[idxItem - 1].b + weightMatrix[idxItem - 1][idxWeight - items[idxItem - 1].w];
                    oldMax = weightMatrix[idxItem - 1][idxWeight];

                    // Update the matrices
                    if (newMax > oldMax) {
                        weightMatrix[idxItem][idxWeight] = newMax;
                        keepMatrix[idxItem][idxWeight] = 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        weightMatrix[idxItem][idxWeight] = oldMax;
                        keepMatrix[idxItem][idxWeight] = 0;
                    }
                }

                // Else, item can't fit; value and weight are the same as before
                else {
                    weightMatrix[idxItem][idxWeight] = weightMatrix[idxItem - 1][idxWeight];
                }
            }
        }

        // Traverse through keepMatrix ([numItems][capacity] -> [1][?])
        // to create solutionSet
        idxWeight = capacity;
        idxItem = numItems;
        for (idxItem; idxItem > 0; idxItem--) {
            if (keepMatrix[idxItem][idxWeight] === 1) {
                solutionSet.push(items[idxItem - 1]);
                idxWeight = idxWeight - items[idxItem - 1].w;
            }
        }
        return { "maxValue": weightMatrix[numItems][capacity], "set": solutionSet };
    }

    function removeItem(items, value) {
        //console.log(items, "items:before");
        //console.log(value, "value");
        let found = false;
        items.forEach(function (e, i, arr) {
            //console.log(e, "e");
            if (e["w"] == value["w"] && !found) {
                items.splice(i, 1);
                found = true;
            }
        });
        //console.log(items, "items:after");
        return items;
    }

    function getTotal(items){
        var s = items.reduce((a,b) => a + parseFloat(b["w"]), 0);
        return s;
    }

    /*
      lengths: array - array of numbers represents the different lengths of cable
      boxes: array - array of numbers represents the different sizes of boxes for cable length
    */
    function main(lengths, boxes) {
        let ret = {
            boxes: {},
            cart: [],
            total: 0
        }

        //ret.total = lengths.reduce((a, b ) => a + b, 0 );
        // sort boxes ascending
        boxes = boxes.sort((b1, b2) => b2 + b1);
        console.log(boxes);
        let items = [];
        lengths.forEach(function (i) {
            items.push({ "w": i, "b": i })
        });
        let grandTotal = getTotal(items);

        ret.total = grandTotal;

        console.log(ret);
        let prevLength = items.length
        while(items.length > 0){
            // get total amount of the items
            let total = getTotal(items)
            // see which box is the smallest we can fit
            let boxSize = 0
            boxes.forEach(function(v,i,a){
                if(v <= total){
                    boxSize = v;
                }
            });
            // break if we can't find a box
            //console.log(boxSize);
            if(boxSize == 0){
                break;
            }
            // invoke knapsack
            let result = knapsack(items, boxSize);
            // if the maxValue == 0 then we actually need to go one box bigger
            if(result["maxValue"] == 0){
                // reset the boxSize
                boxSize = 0;
                boxes.forEach(function(v,i,a){
                    //console.log(boxSize);
                    // we only want to pick the first bigger size
                    if(v >= total && boxSize == 0){
                        //console.log(v);
                        boxSize = v;
                    }
                })

                // if we can't find a boxSize, break
                if(boxSize == 0){
                    break;
                }

                // rerun knapsack with the new size
                result = knapsack(items, boxSize);

            }

            // push the result to the cart
            ret.cart.push(result);

            // remove items that were in the knapsack set
            for (let s in result["set"]) {
                items = removeItem(items, result["set"][s]);
            }

            // break if the prevLength == the items.length, it means we are in a endless loop
            if(items.length == prevLength){
                break;
            }
            // push the box we selected to the ret value
            (boxSize in ret.boxes) ? ret.boxes[boxSize] = ret.boxes[boxSize] + 1 : ret.boxes[boxSize] = 1;

            // reset the prevLength
            prevLength = items.length;
        }

        return ret;

    }


const lengths = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2];
const boxes = [10, 5, 20];
const ret = main(lengths, boxes);
JSON.stringify(ret);
```

Comment: Can you give examples? I am kinda lost in important terms such as drops , it's different lengths and creating drops? If I understand it correctly, since you have a `1k` feet box,  wastage wouldn't probably happen?

Comment: Are the sizes of the boxes random for each problem are all they always 5 10 20?

Comment: Yes. they can be different sizes.

Comment: How does this differ from the target sum (equal or greater), coin change, and related problems?  You should be able to make a straightforward attack (i.e. brute-force solution) on your own.

Comment: @prune, bryan60 is 99% of the way there with a solution to the problem. look at what he did. all i need is a list of the items in each box. please remove the hold on the question.

Comment: If you're getting progress, I'll hope that someone rewrites the problem description to be useful per SO standards.  I don't have the power to individually release the hold; the best I can do is to vote to reopen, which I've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set L = sum of lengths
While L > 0
  Get largest box B where size S <= L OR smallest box
  set numB = Floor division L / B OR 1
  store numB of B
  Subtract numB * B from L
```

you'll need some adjustments for a case where you might have waste (ie need 4 feet of cable but smallest box is 5)

if I were to javascript it:

```js
function getBoxes(lengths, boxes) {
   // sort descending
   boxes = boxes.sort((b1, b2) => b2 - b1); 
   // get the smallest box (needed later)
   const minB = boxes[boxes.length - 1]; 
   // create an object to store my results;
   const boxResult = boxes.reduce((acc, b) => Object.assign(acc, {[b]: 0}), {});
   // sum lengths
   let L = lengths.reduce((sum, l) => sum += l, 0);
   while (L > 0) {
      // get first box less than or equal to L or smallest box
      const B = boxes.find(b => b <= L) || minB;
      // get floor division or 1
      const numB = Math.floor(L / B) || 1;
      // store that number of that box (adding for waste case)
      boxResult[B] += numB;
       // subtract from L
      L -= numB * B;
   }
   // done
   return boxResult;
}

const lengths = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2];
const boxes = [10, 5, 20];

const result = getBoxes(lengths, boxes);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Awesome job!!!! I'm trying to wrap my head around the code. how could I modify it so I could get a list of what items are in each box?

Comment: does it matter? my assumption was that a box of some length of cable could be divided to whatever

Comment: it would be something nice to show the person, this way they wouldn't have to guess what lengths they could make from each box.

Comment: Do the lengths need to “fit” the boxes though, or can I subdivide and splice as needed? Like if my lengths were 7,7,11 then I need 25 cable. But only 7 and 11 “fit” in the 20 box and none would fit in a 5 box, so would the answer be 1 20 and 1 5 (with 0 waste) or 1 20 and 1 10 so that everything fits but with 5ft waste... not being allowed to splice changes the algorithm a lot and makes it significantly more complex

Comment: Yes... the lengths would need to fit the boxes. You are going above and beyond and I thank you for this.

Comment: So the answer would be 1 20 and 1 10 in my example, not 1 20 and 1 5?

Comment: exactly. the answer would be (1)20 and (1)10